# Inner join not show result

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I want to do an inner join but I do not have any result:

```
select 
  t5.tcdv_id, t5.gps_coordx, t5.gps_coordy, 
  t6.status
from
(
  select 
    t3.tcdv_id tcdv_id, t3.reg_date reg_date, 
    t4.CONTROLLERCOMM_STATUS status 
  from 
    SCS_L_SCSCONTROLLERSTATUS t4
    inner join                  
    (
      select 
        t1.tcdv_id tcdv_id,
        max(reg_date) reg_date 
      from 
        SCS_L_SCSCONTROLLERSTATUS t2
      inner join 
      (
        select distinct 
          tcdv_id 
        from 
          SCS_L_SCSCONTROLLERSTATUS 
        where 
          tcdv_id not in('C1010000','C10100000')
      ) t1 
      on 
        t1.tcdv_id=t2.tcdv_id
    group by 
      t1.tcdv_id
  ) t3 
  on 
    t3.tcdv_id=t4.tcdv_id and 
    t3.reg_date=t4.reg_date 
) t6                   
inner join
(
  select 
    t.tcdv_id tcdv_id, t.int_ip int_ip, 
    b.gps_coordx gps_coordx, b.gps_coordy gps_coordy 
  from
    bits.tms_m_node b                     
  inner join  
    tscs.scs_m_intlc@"BITS_TSCS.CORE.TMC.LOCAL" t 
  on 
    t.node_id=b.node_id
) t5 
on 
  t5.tcdv_id=t6.tcdv_id;
```

Comment: Seems like you have no matching rows.

Comment: This query is in a mess.  I'll bet it could be rewritten more simply.  Please include some data.

Comment: Matching row is tcdv_id

Comment: when i run t6 and t5 seperately it shows data

Comment: But do t6 and t5  show *matching* data? If you get no rows from the join then the answer to that appears to be 'no'.

Comment: @HuseynQuliyev That t6 subquery could be rewritten as `SELECT tcdv_id, reg_date, controllercomm_status status, MAX(reg_date) OVER (PARTITION BY tcdv_id) max_reg_date FROM scs_l_scscontrollerstatus WHERE tcdv_id NOT IN ('C1010000', 'C10100000')` and then you would include the condition `t6.max_reg_date = t6.reg_date` in the join clause when joining t6 to the t5 subquery. Much simpler and easier to read (and therefore maintain) than the version you came up with!

Comment: Also check that the data type of `tcdv_id` is the same in the two tables it's coming from (`SCS_L_SCSCONTROLLERSTATUS` and `tscs.scs_m_intlc@"BITS_TSCS.CORE.TMC.LOCAL"`) - maybe one is `varchar2` and the other is `char`, so you're trying to compare padded and unpadded strings?

Comment: Please edit query

Comment: For the query: added commas, some line breaks, and indentation - no changes to the "code" per se. Sometimes problems jump out at you when you can see what's going on.